# Woocommerce checkout steps indicator

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is regards to woocommmece checkout using Wordpress.

I need to find a way to display the total number of steps for buying , from filling the cart till end of the check out .and to highlight the actual step the customer is in at the moment.

From the research I have done, I haven't found anything that could at least guide me in the process of creating this. I looked into displaying breadcrumbs but that isn't exactly what I want.

Anyone who can shed some light on this or perhaps have implemented this before